# Magento: Nick-naming products added to the cart

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a storefront that sells bundled products, sort of like build-your-own-PCs.

Once the customer has selected their desired options, **I'd like them to also give a (nick)name to the product before adding it to their cart**.  This would be a standard text field purely for the customer's reference.

This field will be displayed in the cart, during checkout, and in the order details once the order is submitted.

**What is the best/proper way to implement this user-editable product field?**

I had thought Custom Options would be best, however it states that a "`Bundle with dynamic pricing cannot include custom defined options. Options will not be saved.`"

Answer (score 1):

As I'm aware Magento doesn't have any built in way to implement this. You're options would be to find a third party extension or write a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

I found and implemented the workaround shown here: http://amirshakya.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/custom-options-on-a-bundle-product-in-dynamic-pricing/  It essentially disables the warning and enforcement of that rule.

Yes, I realize this is a bit of a hack, but it works great because:

- The custom option doesn't need to affect the price (which is why Magento blocks it I think)
- It will show both the bundle options and the custom nickname option on the page
- User selections will be saved for both